# iOS: save and then load web page from document directory in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHwbh.png)i want to save this webpage of webview in document directory, for which i do this:

```
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "path")
    let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(text!)/\(pageTitle).html")
    print("path is:\(dataPath)")
    do
        {
            let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: textfield_url.text!)!
            let urlData: NSData = try NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)
            urlData.write(toFile: dataPath.path, atomically: true)

        } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
    }
```

textfield contain current page url.
Now i want to load this webpage from document directory, problem is that my page not loading completely images missing.
For loading code is:

```
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(pageName)
    print("path is:\(dataPath)")
    let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: dataPath.path);

    let requestObj = URLRequest.init(url: url)

    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
```

after loading i get this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuXd7.png)

Comment: i believe what you are saving is the html contents. not the css, img, etc.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, how can i save full webpage with everything css, images etc in document directory???

Comment: may be saving webarchive in document directory may help, and then load the webarchive to web view. (but need to check how webarchive can be saved). check webarchive : https://github.com/takebayashi/STWebArchiver